# Where do I attribute authors with the free icons I used?

Tags: android

The icons I'm using for my app are free to use with attribution, but I'm confused by the wording they use in their instructions: "Place the attribution on the credits/description page of the application."

Does this mean I need to create a separate page in my actual mobile app where I just make a text with the attribution or just place the attribution in the credits page of the app store?

I can't seem to find an answer online.

Bonus question, I just want to make sure, I used a couple of free icons and edited them together to create the actual launcher icon of my app, is that okay to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask the icon authors. Or, ask your attorney.

Comment: _"I used a couple of free icons and edited them together to create the actual launcher icon of my app, is that okay to do?"_ That depends on the specific license of course. But that's off-topic here.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought the "Free to use with attribution" was like a generally known "license". @MarkusKauppinen